# Implementing yahoo stock quote in j2me - white @ fault "redirect " response(301)

Tags: java-me, midp, httpconnection

I was going to implement quote yahoo stock. When it runs, the program does not connect to the specified url I entered.

It shows a mess in emulator like `white @ fault "redirect " response(301)`

Here is my code to connect to the url:

```
public String getQuote() throws IOException,NumberFormatException { 
String url ="http://quote.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=ibm&f=slc1wop"; 
HttpConnection c = null; 
c =(HttpConnection) Connector.open(url,Connector.READ_WRITE, true); 
c.setRequestMethod(HttpConnection.GET); 
InputStream is = c.openInputStream(); 
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(); 
int ch; 
  while ((ch = is.read()) != -1) { 
    sb.append((char) ch); 
  } 
return (sb.toString()); 
}
```